# How to keep gherkin files in sync with automated tests in specflow or other BDD gherkin/cucumber frameworks

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, bdd, specflow

So I'm confused about the process/steps to keep automated tests in sync with gherkin/feature files in specflow.  Assuming the feature files are written in gherkin and checked into git source control.

I see that there is a tool to generate stub automated tests from a gherkin file, and that flows naturally into letting a developer implement those tests.

My question is if the features and spec change, what is the workflow for refactoring or updating those tests to keep it in sync?  Is it done manually by the developer, or does specflow or other BDD driven tools have something to help you manage the refactoring of the test files?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool support that will update the steps when the wanted behavior changes.

The steps that are used for automating the specifications has to be maintained manually in the same way as the steps was implemented when they where new.

Anyone capable of implementing the code used in the automation has to do it. This may be a developer, a tester or someone else with sufficient knowledge about the domain and programming.